# Javascript : Load markers on a Google map with a loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I come for help for a javascript problem.
I'm adding a Google map to my website; this map is currently integrated in my page and works fine.
My problem is that i have a lot of markers to place on the map and i want to use a loop to do it.
The coordinates of the markers are stored in a Site[] table.
For now i have this :

```
// Create markers on the map
for( i = 0; i < Site.length; i++ )
{
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(Site[i][7], Site[i][8]); //7 and 8 are the latitude and longitude of the markers.
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos,
  map: maCarte,   //my map
  title: Site[i][1] //1 is the description of the marker
  }
});
```

And, of course, this doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up with the different parenthesis... If you would indent your code properly, this would be quite obvious.

```
// Create markers on the map
for (i = 0; i < Site.length; i++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(Site[i][7], Site[i][8]); //7 and 8 are the latitude and longitude of the markers.

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: maCarte, //my map
        title: Site[i][1] //1 is the description of the marker
    });
}
```

If it still doesn't work after you corrected this, then problem must be somewhere else. Without knowing the content of the `Site` array, we can't help any further.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/kw93fx44/)</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work but seems to help a little.
My Site table is like this :
Site[0]=[1, 'description',1,'http://192.168.10.60','192.168.3.61.1.1','801','03.22.31.51.73',50.06,1.50];

Comment: Latitude and Longitude are the two last.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Did you check your javascript console for errors? Did you log `Site[i][1]`, `Site[i][7]` and `Site[i][8]` ? We can't help if we don't know how you do your stuff. Provide a working example to reproduce the error.

Comment: What i mean by "doesn't work" is that i don't get errors from the console anymore but the markers don't show.

Comment: Besides, when i create markers without a loop, this works. By that, i mean that i can access the coordinates of Site.

Comment: Wow that's exactly my problem. Thanks a lot. I'll use that

Comment: Oh that's actually from you.

Comment: As mp85 stated below, also make sure you declare your variables correctly. `var marker = ...` and `for (var i=0; ...` etc. which is how it's done in the fiddle.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped! Thx

Comment: This really seems to work, but the markers simply don't appear on the map.
Anyway, i know the loop works, thanks a lot !
First time on StackOverflow and this is already useful :)